# AWS aurora failover, how to refresh the dns?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are using java springboot+mybatis+AWS aurora, I am using the cluster endpoint. When the aurora writes node failover, the read-only node becomes the writes node. The endpoint refers to the new write node. But my application always connects to the original node which becomes a read-only node. So how to solve this problem?

The AWS aurora document:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html

The physical IP address pointed to by the cluster endpoint changes when the failover mechanism promotes a new DB instance to be the read-write primary instance for the cluster. If you use any form of connection pooling or other multiplexing, **be prepared to flush or reduce the time-to-live for any cached DNS information**. Doing so ensures that you don't try to establish a read-write connection to a DB instance that became unavailable or is now read-only after a failover.

Answer (score -1):

We are using MariaDB to solve this problem.

maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

spring-boot auto-configuration:
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver